# Mobile Menu Called Twice - Wordpress Puzzles Theme

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-mobile

I've been trying to fix a problem with my website (http://goo.gl/BctVcb) for several weeks but no luck.

The menu is being called twice when someone is accessing via a mobile platform. The 2 fixes are to remove the mobile theme, which causes other problems, or NG Gallery. NG Gallery seems to cause the problem as disabling it solves the issue, but we have hundreds of galleries that we need.

Has anyone encounter this problem before?

Comment: not a lot of information. Which menu an what is "called twice". Some code would probably also be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't my field of expertise :D (As you can probably guess >.<) The developers of the theme sent us this screenshot to demonstrate what code was causing the problem: http://screencast.com/t/u2YgCKbbWN

Comment: What device are you using?

Comment: It happens on every mobile device apparently. I cannot check them all myself as I don't own the platform but the Windows phone has the problem, and close friends checked with iOS and Android also, same error.

Comment: sorry. this is too vague to give any help.

Comment: Ugh, I'm terribly sorry. I'm trying to explain it best I can :D When I go to the website on my mobile, it displays fine. When I click the main navigation menu a list of options is supposed to drop down. However, it simply loads another menu on top so when I click "Features" the drop down box appears for 0.5 seconds, and then disappears again. This only happens when a visitor is using a mobile device to browse, it does not occur on PC